# Is it possible to chain pseudo classes using Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, pseudo-class

I have an `after:` pseudo element I'm targetting using Tailwind CSS. I want to remove the background of the element when moving up to medium screens.

I know I should be able to do `md:bg-none` AND I can do `after:bg-none`, but can I do them together?

e.g. `md:after:bg-none`

Should this work? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Never mind! I realised I must have overwritten the Tailwind defaults somehow and bg-none wasn't working.

I added bg-none to the taiwind.config file and I was able to run:

```
md:after:bg-none
```

So for anyone else wandering (because there didn't seem to be any other answers elsewhere, it is perfectly possible to chain pseudo-classes together using Tailwind CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Its definitely possible to chain but remember that only the full chain will work:

```
hover:bg-black //black background on hover

focus:bg-black //black background on focus

focus:hover:bg-black //black background on hovering already focused element
```

The latter class won't do anything on hover or focus alone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need both of them, if one of them works then it should be more than enough to meet your needs.

```
md: bg-none
```

Comment: But the element itself already has a background set at medium. It is specifically the background of the after: pseudo-element that I need to remove. Does that make sense?

Comment: @NickyJ if you can share your work, i could try to help you with it. regarding that specific piece of html&css

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've just figured out where I was going wrong. Sorry - first time actually asking anything here!

Comment: No problem, i am also quite new here, what was the problem?

Comment: Answered above :)